# An example of a variety of an ideal of a variety...?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

> I am asked to show an example of some $S \subset k^n$ such that $V(I(S)) \ne S$.

So basically, $S$ is some set of points in $k^n$ a field of $n$ dimensions, and an affine variety, I guess.
I've been thinking of some simple ones say in $k[x]$ or $k[x,y]$ but it's making me start to think there's no such thing(while that's obviously wrong)

Can someone give me an example...? I just cannot imagine how an affine variety's ideal's variety can be different from the original variety and why...

Comment: $S$ need not (and in fact, cannot) be an affine variety.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean it cannot be an affine variety...?

Comment: I mean the condition that $V(I(S)) = S$ is equivalent to the condition that $S$ is a (closed) affine (sub)variety in $k^n$. So if you want an example where the two aren't equal, then $S$ can't be an affine variety, which you've assumed. (Here I'm assuming that $k$ is algebraically closed for simplicity.)

Comment: Algebraic closedness of $k$ is irrelevant and will almost inexorably lead to invocation of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, which is a catastrophically bad idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since $V(I(S))=\bar S$, the Zariski closure of $S$, any non Zariski closed subset of $k^n$ will yield a counterexample.
[Note carefully that algebraic closedness of $k$ is not assumed]
Explicitly, if you take $k=\mathbb C$ and $S=\mathbb Z\subset k^1=\mathbb C^1$, a non Zariski closed subset, you will get $V(I(\mathbb Z))=V(0)=\mathbb C^1$.

Answer (score 0):

For example with $n=1$, take $S$ to be the set of zeroes of some polynomial $P(x)$ with $P(0)\neq 0$, for any such $P$. Then you get everything except the origin in your set. $I(S)=0$ and thus $V(I(S))=\mathbb{A}^1\neq S$.

Comment: Dear Mohan, this is not correct. For example if $P(x)=x-1$ then $S=\{1\}$ and $V(I(S))=V((x-1)k[x])=\{1\}=S$.

Comment: I did not take just one $P(x)$. I said take all such $P$ with $P(0)\neq 0$, take their `zeroes' and the union of all these zeroes. It will have everything except $0$.